# In $\left(C([0,1]), d_{\infty}\right)$, the subset $ A=\{f \in C([0,1]): f(t)>t, \forall t \in[0,1]\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Show that in the metric space $\left(C([0,1]), d_{\infty}\right)$, the subset $$ A=\{f \in C([0,1]): f(t)>t, \forall t \in[0,1]\} $$ is open.

**My try:** I take $x\in A$ and $\epsilon=f(t)-t$.

I take $g$ in the ball $B_{\epsilon}(f)$.

So $f(t)-g(t)<\max|f(t)-g(t)|< \epsilon$ for all $t$.

So
$f(t)-g(t)< f(t)-t$, and hence $g(t)> t$.

Is it right?

Comment: Is $f$ the $x$ you took? Also, your $\epsilon$ doesn't seem well defined.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes sorry

Comment: @Keen-ameteur then how can i take $\epsilon$

Comment: Your solution needs some corrections in my opinion. Your $\epsilon$ should be independent of $t\in [0,1]$. You should choose an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f(t)-t>\epsilon$ for all $t$. You should justify to yourself why such an $\epsilon$ must exist.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your proof is that **it is not clear that a $t$-independent positive $\epsilon$ exists, such that $f(t)-t>\epsilon$, especially because you have not used the fact that the set of continuous functions on a compact set ($[0,1]$) is under question.** In the following, we prove that such $\epsilon>0$ exists.

We prove that for any $h\in A$, $\inf_{0\le x\le 1}\{h(x)-x\}>0$. Assume by contrary that $\inf_{0\le x\le 1}\{h(x)-x\}=0$. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\in[0,1]^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} h(x_n)-x_n=0$. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, there exists some subsequence $\{x_{y_n}\}_{n=1}^\infty\in[0,1]^\infty$ that converges to some $x^*\in[0,1]$. This, by definition of continuity of $h(x)$, implies that $h(x^*)=x^*$, which is a contradiction. Hence, $\inf_{0\le x\le 1}\{h(x)-x\}>0$ and the proof is complete. Now, simply regard any $\epsilon<\inf_{0\le x\le 1}\{h(x)-x\}$ and finish your proof cheerfully.

**Shedding light on the problem with your proof**

If the set of continuous functions is defined over any non-compact set $S$, it is possible to find functions $h\in A$ such that $\inf_{S}\{h(x)-x\}=0$. For example, consider the set of continuous functions over $(0,1)$. Then, for $h(t)=\sqrt t$ we have $$\inf_{t\in(0,1)}h(t)-t=\inf_{t\in(0,1)}\sqrt t-t=0,$$implying that no $\epsilon>0$ exists such that $h(t)-t>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If $f\in A$, then $g(t):=f(t)-t$ is continuous and $g(t)>0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. There should be some reason, *using that $g$ is continuous on a closed interval*, why there exists some $\epsilon>0$,  such that $g(t)\geq\epsilon>0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$.